# Bisecting an angle with a right-angled bent ruler (that can coordinate the vertex and both edges)

Tags: euclidean-geometry

This thesis claims that you can construct any point constructible with ruler and compass with only a "bent ruler" -- that is, a pair of moveable rays joined at a specific angle.

["Euclidean constructions: alternate tools to the traditional compass and straightedge" by Sandra Kay Birrell, California State University, 1983](https://scholarworks.calstate.edu/downloads/0c483n19f)

However it does not provide constructions themselves with bent rulers. It seems with specifically a right-angled ruler (where the angle between the two rays is a right angle) it is quite difficult to bisect an angle. How can it be done?

(Note that this is a different question to the [existing similar one on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093568/is-it-possible-to-construct-the-angle-bisector-of-two-lines-with-only-a-right-an), as the other one explicitly excludes the ability to coordinate the vertex and the two rays simultaneously.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, on one of the rays of the angle, plot a point so you have a segment. Then bisect that segment. (This can be done by constructing a rectangle and its diagonals, then dropping a perpendicular from the intersection of the diagonals.)[image: Image of construction of midpoint of a segment on an angle]

Then, construct a ray parallel to the other ray of the angle through point M. (This is done by constructing a perpendicular to that ray, and then another to that one through M.)

[image: Construction of the parallel ray]

Now we can use the technique you mentioned. Because M is the midpoint of A and B, it is also the center of the circle containing diameter AB. Thus, using [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), we can say that the right triangle formed by the bent ruler is inscribed in semicircle AB, and thus the right angle's vertex is the same distance from M.

[image: Procedure using the right angled ruler]

Since we've now essentially created a parallelogram with two congruent consecutive sides, it's a rhombus, and thus the diagonal will bisect the angle. Which completes the construction.[image: Finished construction]